# How to deal with “SettingWithCopyWarning” in a for loop if statement

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say column A is time-based, column B is salary.

I am using an if statement within a for loop trying to find "all salaries that are less than the previous one BUT ALSO greater than the following one." Then assign a new value ('YES') to another column (column C) of the rows that fulfill the condition. Finally, I want to grab the first column A that fulfill the above conditions.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
In [1]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['2007q3','2007q4','2008q1','2008q2','2008q3','2008q4','2009q1','2009q2','2009q3'], 
                   'B':[14938, 14991, 14899, 14963, 14891, 14577, 14375, 14355, 14402]})
df['C'] = pd.Series()
df

Out [1]:
      A       B      C
0   2007q3  14938   NaN
1   2007q4  14991   NaN
2   2008q1  14899   NaN
3   2008q2  14963   NaN
4   2008q3  14891   NaN
5   2008q4  14577   NaN
6   2009q1  14375   NaN
7   2009q2  14355   NaN
8   2009q3  14402   NaN
```

The following code does the work but is showing the "SettingWithCopyWarning" warning, I am not sure which parts of the code is causing the problem...

```
In [2]:
for i in range(1, len(df)-1):
    if (df['B'][i] < df['B'][i-1]) & (df['B'][i] > df['B'][i+1]):
       df['C'][i] = 'YES'
df

Out [2]: 
      A       B      C
0   2007q3  14938   NaN
1   2007q4  14991   NaN
2   2008q1  14899   NaN
3   2008q2  14963   NaN
4   2008q3  14891   YES
5   2008q4  14577   YES
6   2009q1  14375   YES
7   2009q2  14355   NaN
8   2009q3  14402   NaN

In [3]: df['A'][df['C'] == 'YES'].iloc[0]
Out [3]:'2008q3'
```

Or maybe there's a better way to have the job done. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

For more details on why you got **SettingWithCopyWarning**, I would suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/9274732). It is mostly because selecting the column `df['C']` and then selecting the row with `[i]` does a **"chained assignment"** that is flagged this way when you do `df['C'][i] = 'YES'`

For what you try to do, you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) on the column B such as:

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where((df.B < df.B.shift()) & (df.B > df.B.shift(-1)), 'YES', np.nan)
```

and you get the same output.